# Enable resetZoom button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Something is wrong for me. I created a chart using version 1.2.2 and the reset button worked fine, no problem at all the reset button is there ("Redefinir Zoom")

[image]

But when I updated to version 1.3.4 the button is gone, the button does not appear.

I used the same position code on the .js file

```
position:{align:"right",x:-43,y:-56}}}
```

Already tried editing it and no luck, the button does not appear.

Is there any setting to enable and disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How did you manage to show that button? Probably you were using some old inner function to achieve that which doesn't exists in 1.3.x. To show that button try to call `chart.showResetZoom()`

Comment: I used no functions for it, I just used the zoom and it appears. I included the command you told me and got a javascript error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'showResetZoomButton'". Ok, worked using chart.showResetZoom();

Comment: Ok, the thing is, the old version button worked only when I entered the zoom mode, now the button is always there, I need to show it only when the gfx is zoomed.

Comment: I think the problem is on my side, it appears from stock that the button on Highstock works fine on new versions without calling the function, http://jsfiddle.net/UEsWX/

Comment: Thanks, but, what's wrong? Why it's working for me on one version and not on another, what changed? I'm using the same settings, just changing the javascript filename, something is really wrong :(

Comment: Without live example it's hard to guess what is wrong. Do you have any other errors in console? Try to recreate issue on jsFiddle.